# How to pass an object to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to pass a class object to another activity via intent. Here is my class code:

```
public class Model
{
    private String Name;
    private ArrayList<Trim> trim;

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Trim> getTrim()
    {
        return trim;
    }

    public void setTrim(ArrayList<Trim> trim)
    {
        this.trim = trim;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in this code? Post the activities code

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2139134/760489

Comment: Implement using Parcelable or serializable. [Implementation example](https://www.techjini.com/blog/passing-objects-via-intent-in-android/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To pass an object to another activity you need to implement Parcelable.

Review *[Writing Parcelable classes for Android](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/)* carefully. Here they are using Hashmap to store the values and pass the object to another class.

### OR

---

Make one class, `ObjectA`. In that, I used all the setter and getter methods.

```
package com.ParcableExample.org;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * A basic object that can be parcelled to
 * transfer between objects.
 */

public class ObjectA implements Parcelable
{
    private String strValue = null;
    private int intValue = 0;

    /**
     * Standard basic constructor for non-parcel
     * object creation.
     */

    public ObjectA()
    {
    }

    /**
     *
     * Constructor to use when re-constructing object
     * from a parcel.
     *
     * @param in a parcel from which to read this object.
     */

    public ObjectA(Parcel in)
    {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    /**
     * Standard getter
     *
     * @return strValue
     */
    public String getStrValue()
    {
        return this.strValue;
    }

    /**
     * Standard setter
     *
     * @param strValue
     */

    public void setStrValue(String strValue)
    {
        this.strValue = strValue;
    }


    /**
     * Standard getter
     *
     * @return intValue
     */
    public Integer getIntValue()
    {
        return this.intValue;
    }

    /**
     * Standard setter
     *
     * @param strValue
     */
    public void setIntValue(Integer intValue)
    {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        // We just need to write each field into the
        // parcel. When we read from parcel, they
        // will come back in the same order

        dest.writeString(this.strValue);
        dest.writeInt(this.intValue);
    }

    /**
     *
     * Called from the constructor to create this
     * object from a parcel.
     *
     * @param in parcel from which to re-create object.
     */
    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        // We just need to read back each
        // field in the order that it was
        // written to the parcel

        this.strValue = in.readString();
        this.intValue = in.readInt();
    }

    /**
    *
    * This field is needed for Android to be able to
    * create new objects, individually or as arrays.
    *
    * This also means that you can use use the default
    * constructor to create the object and use another
    * method to hyrdate it as necessary.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator()
    {
        @Override
        public ObjectA createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new ObjectA(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new ObjectA[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Then make one Activity that is used to send the Object to another activity.

```
package com.ParcableExample.org;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ParcableExample extends Activity
{
    private Button btnClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                ObjectA obj = new ObjectA();
                obj.setIntValue(1);
                obj.setStrValue("Chirag");

                Intent i = new Intent(ParcableExample.this,MyActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("com.package.ObjectA", obj);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now finally make one another activity that read the Object and get the value from that.

```
package com.ParcableExample.org;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ObjectA obj = bundle.getParcelable("com.package.ObjectA");

        Log.i("---------- Id   ",":: "+obj.getIntValue());
        Log.i("---------- Name ",":: "+obj.getStrValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `Serializable` in your `Model` class. Then, to pass a `Model` object from source `Activity` to destination `Activity`, use the following code in the source `Activity`:

```
Model objModel = new Model();
Intent modelActivity = (Model.this, detail.class);
intent.putExtra("ModelObject", objModel);
```

And this code in the destination `Activity`:

```
Model modelObject = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ModelObject");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your responce.. but when receive the same object in destination activity than error in statement...                    model =   this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ModelClass");

Comment: whats the error or logcat output of the same?

Comment: Then problem is in your code. Check it properly. You should write: Model modelObject = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ModelObject");

Comment: yes i have wrote same code as you have describe... syntax error is casting error. change model object is serializable...i also implement serial.. in my class Model.

Comment: As per your above comment and as per this comment http://goo.gl/DsUTT, you can try this: Model modelObject = (Model) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ModelObject");

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement `Parcelable` interface and then you can send it to another `Activity` using:

```
MyClass myObject;
//...
intent=new Intent(this, MyAnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mydata", (Parcelable )myObject);
this.startActivity(intent);
```