# Pass a list to another page using android

Tags: android

I'm just wondering is there a chance to pass a
 `List<'object'>samplelist= new arrayList<'object'>()`
to another page. Because what i'm doing is something like of `addToCart`. I have a `listview` with an `onClickEvent` that will add an item to the list. Or is there another way to do it beside a list?. I just need an idea so please be nice.

Comment: object must implment parcelable

Comment: @raghunandan tnx for the reply but what do you mean by parcelable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable. search on stavkoverflow you will find many similar posts

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743084/how-to-pass-a-class-object-in-another-activity or my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another/21250450#21250450