# how to pass class from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I want to pass the class and content of the class from one activity to another activity.

For example i have two activities activity A and activity B.

i created a class in activity B.

i want to pass this class from activity B back to activity A.

ANOTHER QUESTION IS THAT:

How i can put text loaded from the edittext to the two button.

For example there is a one edittext and two buttons.

i want to load the text from the edittext to the two button but difference text at the same time.
for example i want to set the text button1 to the one button and button2 to the another button and these text loaded from the edit text at the same time

Comment: It is better to ask one question at a time. As I read your question, my impression is that you want Stack Overflow people do everything for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an object to another activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743084/how-to-pass-an-object-to-another-activity)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: see this . hope this will you                                                                                                                                                                                      http://android-help1.blogspot.com/2015/07/android-send-value-string-or-int-from.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a static class that can be called from both activities.

```
public class A {
   public A(SomeObject obj) {

   }

   public static class B {

   }
}
```